# Why does thrust::sort for customized data needs a default constuctor while STL::sort does't?

Tags: c++, sorting, stl, cuda, thrust

I am trying to sort a set of triangles by minimum x-coordinate using thrust:

```
struct real3 
{
    float x, y, z;
};

struct triangle
{
    real3 p1, p2, p3;

    float Xmin, Xmax;

    triangle(real3 ip1, real3 ip2, real3 ip3) :p1(ip1), p2(ip2), p3(ip3)
    {
        Xmax = (p1.x > p2.x) ? ((p1.x > p3.x) ? p1.x : p3.x) : ((p2.x > p3.x) ? p2.x : p3.x);
        Xmin = (p1.x < p2.x) ? ((p1.x < p3.x) ? p1.x : p3.x) : ((p2.x < p3.x) ? p2.x : p3.x);
    }
};

bool triangle_less_Xmin(const triangle& f, const triangle& b)
{
    return f.Xmin < b.Xmin;
}
```

and

```
thrust::device_vector<triangle> devXXX(XXX);
thrust::sort(devXXX.begin(), devXXX.end(), triangle_less_Xmin);
```

but at compile time, an error message complained that "no default constructor exists for class tringle". But if I use std::vector for the sort like below:

```
std::vector<triangle> sss;
std::sort(sss.begin(), sss.end(), triangle_less_Xmin);
```

Everything gose well. Also, if I add **triangle(){}** to the struct, thrust compiles well, too.
So, what is the problem? As far as I know, sorting doesn't neet to creat new data. Am I supposed to do something special in default constuctor?

---

**Edit 30 minutes later**

I found this in thrust source code, though do not really know the exact meaning. This is where the error pointed to:

```
__host__ inline static result_type host_path(execution_policy<DerivedPolicy> &exec, Pointer ptr)
{
  // when called from host code, implement with assign_value
  // note that this requires a type with default constructor
  result_type result;

  thrust::host_system_tag host_tag;
  cross_system<thrust::host_system_tag, DerivedPolicy> systems(host_tag, exec);
  assign_value(systems, &result, ptr);

  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have both the source of the error and the solution already in your question, and the compiler provided a very informative error message.

But for the sake of completeness, Thrust is requiring that your `triangle` class has a default constructor, and although I'm not sure the code you posted pinpoints the exact place in the codebase (or your `devXXX` is actually a host vector and not a device vector), somewhere thrust is instantiating your class without arguments, causing the failure you see.

In general, when defining a class with an explicit non-default constructor, you should also provide your own default constructor, because providing *any* constructor definition disables the compiler's implicit default constructor.

So this is OK:

```
struct triangle
{
    real3 p1, p2, p3;

    float Xmin, Xmax;

};

triangle t;  // Implicit default constructor called
```

and this is OK

```
struct triangle
{
    real3 p1, p2, p3;

    float Xmin, Xmax;

    triangle() {};
    triangle(real3 ip1, real3 ip2, real3 ip3) :p1(ip1), p2(ip2), p3(ip3)
    {
        Xmax = (p1.x > p2.x) ? ((p1.x > p3.x) ? p1.x : p3.x) : ((p2.x > p3.x) ? p2.x : p3.x);
        Xmin = (p1.x < p2.x) ? ((p1.x < p3.x) ? p1.x : p3.x) : ((p2.x < p3.x) ? p2.x : p3.x);
    }
};

triangle  t; // Explicit default constructor called
```

but your definition

```
struct triangle
{
    real3 p1, p2, p3;

    float Xmin, Xmax;

    triangle(real3 ip1, real3 ip2, real3 ip3) :p1(ip1), p2(ip2), p3(ip3)
    {
        Xmax = (p1.x > p2.x) ? ((p1.x > p3.x) ? p1.x : p3.x) : ((p2.x > p3.x) ? p2.x : p3.x);
        Xmin = (p1.x < p2.x) ? ((p1.x < p3.x) ? p1.x : p3.x) : ((p2.x < p3.x) ? p2.x : p3.x);
    }
};

triangle t; // Syntax error here, no default constructor
```

is not OK because you have overridden the compiler's default constructor without providing your own. You should regard the fact that your class works with `std::sort` as an accident, rather than any kind of deficiency in Thrust.

Comment: OK, I agree with "somewhere thrust is instantiating your class without arguments". Actually, I now decide to use sort_by_key instead to save some memory for the vector.